# how can i get the right output when looping through vectors?

Tags: c++

I'm not getting the right output when looping through this vector and I'm not sure why

```
vector<string> words = {"once","i","was","seven"};
for(int i=0;i<=words.size();i++){
    cout<<words[i]<<endl;
    for(int j =0; j<=words.size();j++){
        cout<<words[j]<<endl;
    }
}
```

this code should print: `once once i was seven i once i was seven was once i was seven seven once i was seven`, but it prints:`once once i was seven` , how can i fix it

Comment: Well, `words.size()` is obviously 4. Your `for` loop, therefore, goes from 0 to 4. Next step: count every number from 0 to 4 on your fingers, and see how many fingers you have to use to count each and every number starting with 0 and ending with 4. Hint: it's not four.

Comment: Use < instead of <=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After printing "once once i was seven", it would be crashing since the words size is 4 and you are looping 5 elements(from i = 0 to 4 and words[4] would be undefined behavior). Just remove the equal sign from the condition and you are good to go.

```
vector<string> words = {"once","i","was","seven"};
for(int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++){
    cout << words[i] << endl;
    for(int j = 0; j < words.size(); j++){
        cout << words[j] << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
vector<string> words = {"once","i","was","seven"};

words[0] == "once"
words[1] == "i"
words[2] == "was"
words[3] == "seven"
```

`<= words.size()` makes the loop take you to

`words[4] == <undefined behaviour>`

So, the maximum index is `size()-1`. You can often avoid the hazzle by using range based for loops:

```
for(const auto& outer_word : words) {
    cout<< outer_word << endl;
    for(const auto& word : words) {
        cout << word << "\n";
    }
}
```